# Not getting service result in Json Format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf, service

**IService.cs**

```
    //it is working fine with Xml
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/PrintProductCategory",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    List<ProductCategory> GetProductCategory();

    //it is not working with Json
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Print",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<ProductCategory> GetProductCategory();
```

**Service.cs**

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class Service : IService
{
    ARserviceEntities de = new ARserviceEntities();

    public List<ProductCategory> GetProductCategory()
    {
        var procat = from t in de.ProductCategories select t;
        return procat.ToList();
    }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServBehave">
        <!--Endpoint for REST-->
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restPoxBehavior" contract="IService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServBehave">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <!--Behavior for the REST endpoint for Help enability-->
        <behavior name="restPoxBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ARserviceEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.Model.csdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=GOVINDA-PC;initial catalog=ARservice;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=sa_12345;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Explanation :**

Here my rest service working fine with XML.But when i am using **ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json** then i am getting error on webpage is that **No data recived.**
But it is workig fine with XML.so please help for this problem where i am doing mistake.

Comment: I reproduced your code exactly and the issue doesn't happen here using Chrome or Fiddler for the requests.

Comment: @Carlos Vítor Barros i'm using of chrome for the requests.

Comment: And i Tried with fiddler also but i am getting fiddler error "[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could that what is problem in my case.

**IService.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Print",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<ProductCategory> GetProductCategory();
```

**Service.cs :**

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class Service : IService
{
    ARserviceEntities de = new ARserviceEntities();

    public List<ProductCategory> GetProductCategory()
    {
        var procat = from t in de.ProductCategories select t;
        return procat.ToList();
    }
}
```

And my `XML` File was also right.

**What was the problem :**

problem was that i was using of `.EDMX` for database.

**Solution**

I Just use `.dbml` for database.And I Could solve my problem.

**Remark :**

Whenever you are making `WCF Service` in `visual studio 2010` then use `.dbml` instead of `.edmx`. if you want to retrieve result in `json` or `xml`format.
If Someone is fencing like my problem so they can try this answer.

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using fiddler to actually see what is going on HTTP-traffic-wise. See http://fiddler2.com/.

Comment: I'm getting fiddler error '[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes'

Answer (score 0):

I had this working on one of my recent projects, just checked my config and I can't see anything obviously different with yours. Only thing I can see that’s different (bit of a long shot) is that I’ve specified the [WebGet] attribute on the concrete class implementation, and used [WebInvoke]

So IService.cs would become..

```
[OperationContract]
List<ProductCategory> GetProductCategory();
```

and Service.cs would be..

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class Service : IService
{
    ARserviceEntities de = new ARserviceEntities();

    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Print", Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<ProductCategory> GetProductCategory()
    {
        var procat = from t in de.ProductCategories select t;
        return procat.ToList();
    }
}
```

Can't see why it would make a difference, but might be worth trying!